# IllegalArgument exception in custom setter after upgrading to JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, el, illegalargumentexception

After upgrading to JSF2 (probably) one special accessor in an `.xhtml` file generates `IllegalArgumentExceptions` but I can't really find out why. Running the app on my local JBoss (4.2.2) does not generate this exception but this can be related to a difference between debug and live data.

Following stack trace is generated that I could extract from the production server log:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /xy/xy-subtemplate1.xhtml @131,45 value="#{someClass.someProperty}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:114)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:93)
    ... 37 more
```

`someClass` is being iterated over in a list and has the following methods to access `someProperty`:

```
public int getSomeProperty() {
    return this.getSomeRelatedEnum().ordinal();
}

public void setSomeProperty( final int index) {
    this.setSomeRelatedEnum( SomeRelatedEnum.fromOrdinal( index) );
}
```

How can this lead to the `IllegalArgumentException` mentioned above?

Comment: Can you post the fragment of the xhtml or jsp of the iteration and where this property is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen when the setter method after all expects a different argument type than the one which is provided from EL on.

I *guess* that it's related to the fact that hardcoded/unconverted numbers in EL are by default treated as `long` and not as `int`. Try either changing the `int` to be `long`, or providing an explicit integer converter on the input component like so `<h:someInput converter="javax.faces.Integer">`.

By the way, why don't you just get/set the enum itself directly? Getting/setting the enum by its ordinal is whacky.

Comment: Thanks for the enum directly hint. The code isn't mine, just discovered that it leads to some problems. So I'd change `someProperty` to the enum type and make a getter/setter with enum? Just like any other long, String, whatsoever?